# Markup items in other files on xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, markup

Hi, guys.

I'm using Xcode to continue an existing app and I know the best way to document this specific project is through markups (/// instead of //). Problem is: There are too many functions and using markups to explain all of them would make the code difficult to visualize. Instead, I really want to markup variables, functions, methods and so on... but in other files if it's possible.

Can I markup a function declared in another ".swift" file, somehow? How? I realized my code would improve a lot with those markups to my co-workers, but I've got to really emphasize how illegible the files that variables/functions are declared could become.

PS: StackOverflow's newbie here. If anything goes different than our community's guidelines, please let me know.

Thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: You should write your comments/markup next to the code they are describing anything else would only mean more work, much lower maintainability and general confusion IMO.

Comment: It usually makes sense, but the project is gigantic and markups in general only make things easier to visualize given that you only have to point your mouse to know details (summary, parameters, etc...). Just an opinion, but I guess in cases like this, external markups are justifiable, although I don't know if they're possible.

Only seems problematic because it's right above declarations, and as far as I know, I can't declare a function and "make" that function later.

Comment: @Guaringue Xcode tip - do `control + command + up arrow` to see the interface for your file. If you have documented things like protocols/classes and implement/inherit them for example, you will also see the documentation 'copied' over